# How can I make in array in vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My vue component like this :

```
<template>
    ...
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li v-for="category in categories">
                ... 
                    <input type="checkbox" :value="category.id" :checked="category.id in_array(categoryCountry)">  
                ...
            </li>
        </ul>
    ...
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['categoryCountry', 'categories'],
    }
</script>
```

I want to change condition in the input

categoryCountry is array, for example `array(1,2,3)`

So if category.id in array of categoryCountry, then it will checked

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The best and simple answer.** using "includes" it check if the data exist in array.

**example:**

```
[].includes(something);
```

**answer on your codes.**

```
<input type="checkbox" :value="category.id" :checked="categoryCountry.includes(category.id)">
```

Comment: which is exactly what I wrote

Answer (score 0):

using v-if you can pass a function so, you can make a method in vue that checks your array like

```
checkInArray: (needle, haystack) {
    return haystack.includes(needle)
}
```

The on your input

```
<input v-if="checkInArray(categoryCountry, categories)"
```

Array.prototype.includes() returns a bool true/false which is enough to satisfy a conditional v-if

Answer (score 0):

If you receive an array and you need to display each item of the array as an input checkbox you should iterate through each array item:

```
// Template example
<div id='check_box_sample'>
  <div v-for="category in categoryCountries">
    <input 
      type="checkbox" 
      :id="category"
      :value="category"
      v-model="checkedCategories">
    <label 
      :for="category">
      {{ category }}
    </label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <span>Checked names: {{ checkedCategories }}</span>
</div>
```

So for each iteration on the `v-for="category in categoryCountries"` you create an input type checkbox, you have to define an id `:id="category"` and a value `:value="category"`since this is only a simple example I just use the same array item.

You may want to see a [working example](https://codepen.io/rorellanam/pen/XeGmxX?editors=1000)

I hope this help you.